# menuItemOutput and renderMenu with modules - shinydashboard R

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I have a problem with `menuItemOutput` and `renderMenu` in combination with several modules. The dashboard should start at the start-page. When clicking on the button on this page, the other tabs (e.g. Dashboard) should appear in the menu (in reality the button would start a calculation and the solution will be displayed in the following tabs). Unfortunately, the new tab does not appear after clicking the button. I think the connection between the two scripts might not work, but I don't find the mistake. Here are my shortened scripts:

app.R:

```
ui <- dashboardPagePlus(
  
  #...shortened....
  
  sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(
    collapsed = TRUE,
    sidebarMenu(
      id = "navbar",
      menuItem("Start",
               tabName = "page_start",
               icon = icon("play")),
      
      menuItemOutput("rend_dashboard"),
      
      #...shortened....    
      
      
    )
  ),
  
  body <- dashboardBody(
    tags$script(HTML("$('body').addClass('fixed');")),
    tabItems(
      # Tab Start
      tabItem(tabName = "page_start",
              startUi("Start")),
      
      # Tab Dashboard
      tabItem(tabName = "page_dashboard",
              overviewUi("Overview")),
      
      #...shortened....
      
    )
  )
 
)


server <- function(input, output, session) {
  startServer("Start")
  overviewServer("Overview")
  #...shortened....
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

start.R:

```
    #UI-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    startUi <- function(id) {
      ns <- NS(id)
      
      fluidPage(
        
        #...shortened....
        actionButton(
          inputId = ns("start_btn"),
          label = "Start",
          icon = icon("play-circle")
        ),
        
        #...shortened....
      )
    }
    
    #Server---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    startServer <- function(id) {
      moduleServer(id,
                   function(input, output, session) {
                     
                     #Confirm button
                     observeEvent(input$start_btn, {
                       
                         #Sidebar update
                         output$rend_dashboard <- renderMenu({
                           menuItem(
                             "Dashboard",
                             tabName = "page_dashboard",
                             icon = icon("dashboard")
                           )
                       } 
                 })
                 
               })
  
}
```

Thank you in advance!
In addition: in case it is easier to disable the possibility to click on the menu item and show a "blocked" symbol when clicking on the menu item it is also fine for me.

EDIT (regarding answer of YBS):
initially I planned to use also the shinyWidget pop-up. The following expression would have been in the start.R server function. The Dashboard page should be displayed after the SweetAlert "start_confi_true" was confirmend with "Yes".

```
#Confirm button
                 observeEvent(input$start_btn, {
                   #browser()
                   if (input$start_check_promo == TRUE) {
                     confirmSweetAlert(
                       session = session,
                       inputId = "start_confi_true",
                       title = "Do you want to start the calculation?",
                       type = "warning",
                       btn_labels = c("No", "Yes")
                     )

                     #Sidebar update
                     reactive(input$start_btn)


                   } else
                   confirmSweetAlert(
                     session = session,
                     inputId = "start_confi_false",
                     title = "Please check the option side and try again",
                     type = "error",
                     btn_labels = c("Okay")
                   )
                   })
```

Comment: `overviewServer` and `overviewUi` are not shown here.

Answer (score 0):

As you are displaying the `menuItemOutput` in the sidebar of the main `ui`, you can use the `observeEvent` in the server side, and just pass the action button from `startServer`.  Try this

```
library(shinydashboardPlus)

#UI-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
startUi <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
  fluidPage(

    #...shortened....
    actionButton(
      inputId = ns("start_btn"),
      label = "Start",
      icon = icon("play-circle")
    ),

    plotOutput(ns("p1"))
    #...shortened....
  ))
}

### startServer---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
startServer <- function(id) {
  moduleServer(id,
               function(input, output, session) {
                 output$p1 <- renderPlot(plot(cars))

                 #Confirm button
                 reactive(input$start_btn)

               })
}

### runUi  --------------------------
runUi <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    checkboxInput(ns("start_check_promo"), "start check promo", TRUE),
    plotOutput(ns("norm"))
    #...shortened....
  )
}

### runServer---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
runServer <- function(id, startbtn) {
  moduleServer(id,
               function(input, output, session) {
                 ns <- session$ns
                 observeEvent(startbtn(), {

                   output$norm <- renderPlot({hist(rnorm(500))})
                   
                   if (input$start_check_promo == TRUE) {
                     confirmSweetAlert(
                       session = session,
                       inputId = "start_confi_true",
                       title = "Do you want to start the calculation?",
                       type = "warning",
                       btn_labels = c("No", "Yes")
                     )
                     
                   } else
                     confirmSweetAlert(
                       session = session,
                       inputId = "start_confi_false",
                       title = "Please check the option side and try again",
                       type = "error",
                       btn_labels = c("Okay")
                     )

                 })

               })
}

ui <- dashboardPagePlus(
  header <- dashboardHeaderPlus(),
  #...shortened....

  sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(
    collapsed = TRUE,
    sidebarMenu(
      id = "navbar",
      menuItem("Start",
               tabName = "page_start",
               icon = icon("play")) ,
      menuItem("Second",
               tabName = "page_dashboard",
               icon = icon("home")) ,

      menuItemOutput("rend_dashboard")

      #...shortened....


    )
  ),

  body <- dashboardBody(
    #tags$script(HTML("$('body').addClass('fixed');")),
    tabItems(
      # Tab Start
      tabItem(tabName = "page_start",
              startUi("Start")),

      # Tab Dashboard
      tabItem(tabName = "page_dashboard", runUi("mod2")
               ),
      tabItem(tabName = "page_dashboard2", plotOutput("unif")
      )

      #...shortened....

    )
  )

)


server <- function(input, output, session) {
  btn <-  startServer("Start")
  runServer("mod2",btn)

  observeEvent(btn(), {

    #Sidebar update
    output$rend_dashboard <- renderMenu({
      menuItem(
        "Dashboard",
        tabName = "page_dashboard2",
        icon = icon("dashboard")
      )
    })

  })

  output$unif <- renderPlot({hist(runif(500))})

  #overviewServer("Overview")
  #...shortened....
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The button is working. However, the content in the main panel does not change when clicking on the Dashboard menu. Would that also work with confirmSweetAlert (shinyWidgets package) after pressing the confirm button of the pop-up?

Comment: @user15092124, please try the updated code.

Comment: thanks. I found the error regarding the dashboard page: the tabItem was as a commend in my version. Regarding the confirmSweetAlert: I just added the additional code in the post.

Comment: @user15092124, updated code is working with confirmSweetAlert.

Comment: One additional question: now the whole start.R page is observed if some reactive is happening, right? is it also possible to track only a specific part? I maybe want to add other reactive functions on start.R  later without being tracked by the app.R (to display the tabs).